# Delphi XE5 TRESTRequest getting ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: rest, ssl, indy, delphi-xe5

I'm getting the error

> REST request failed! Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

using the TREST components, here is the example code -- full unit code below
seems to be specific to the url link e.g. other https: calls work fine

```
function Getcall_UsingRest : String;
var
  fRstclnt1: TRESTClient;
  fRstrqst1: TRESTRequest;
  fRstrspns1: TRESTResponse;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    fRstclnt1:= TRESTClient.Create('https://au-api.basiq.io');
    fRstrqst1:= TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    fRstrspns1:= TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
    try
      fRstrqst1.Client := fRstclnt1;
      fRstrqst1.Response := fRstrspns1;

      fRstrqst1.Execute;
      result := fRstrspns1.Content;
    finally
      fRstclnt1.Free;
      fRstrqst1.Free;
      fRstrspns1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      result := e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

---

I have been trying the following to try and fix but i haven't been able to get it to work

using TIdHTTP component i get the same error

```
function Getcall_UsingHTTP_WithSameIssue : String;
var
  fIdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  fresp: TMemoryStream;
  fMySL : TStringList;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    fIdHTTP1:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(fIdHTTP1);
      fIdHTTP1.IOHandler := fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;

      fresp := TMemoryStream.Create;
      fMySL := TStringList.Create;
      try
        fIdHTTP1.Get('https://au-api.basiq.io', fresp);
        fresp.Position := 0;
        fMySL.LoadFromStream( fresp );
        result := fMySL.Text;
      finally
        fMySL.Free;
        fresp.Free;
      end;
    finally
      fIdHTTP1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      result := e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

there is a fix for this which is to put

```
procedure OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL;
  const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT; const AType, AMsg: String);
begin
  SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host);
end;
```

onto the fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.OnStatusInfoEx := OnStatusInfoEx;

the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component is buried deep in the TRESTClient and i haven't been able to find a way to see if i can apply the fix above to work on the TRESTClient

can someone help with how to get the TREST to be able to communicate

---

here is the full source code for the examples above

```
unit RestExample;

interface
uses
  System.Generics.Collections
, REST.Types
, REST.Client
, sysutils
, IdHTTP
, IdSSLOpenSSL
, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders, IdCTypes
, system.Classes
;

function Getcall_UsingRest : String;
function Getcall_UsingHTTP_WithSameIssue : String;
function Getcall_UsingHTTP_WithFix : String;

type
  TCustomIdHTTP = class(TIdHTTP)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  private
    procedure OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL; const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT; const AType, AMsg: String);
  end;

implementation


function Getcall_UsingRest : String;
var
  fRstclnt1: TRESTClient;
  fRstrqst1: TRESTRequest;
  fRstrspns1: TRESTResponse;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    fRstclnt1:= TRESTClient.Create('https://au-api.basiq.io');
    fRstrqst1:= TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    fRstrspns1:= TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
    try
      fRstrqst1.Client := fRstclnt1;
      fRstrqst1.Response := fRstrspns1;

      fRstrqst1.Execute;
      result := fRstrspns1.Content;
    finally
      fRstclnt1.Free;
      fRstrqst1.Free;
      fRstrspns1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      result := e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;

function Getcall_UsingHTTP_WithSameIssue : String;
var
  fIdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  fresp: TMemoryStream;
  fMySL : TStringList;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    fIdHTTP1:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(fIdHTTP1);
      fIdHTTP1.IOHandler := fIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;

      fresp := TMemoryStream.Create;
      fMySL := TStringList.Create;
      try
        fIdHTTP1.Get('https://au-api.basiq.io', fresp);
        fresp.Position := 0;
        fMySL.LoadFromStream( fresp );
        result := fMySL.Text;
      finally
        fMySL.Free;
        fresp.Free;
      end;
    finally
      fIdHTTP1.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      result := e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;

function Getcall_UsingHTTP_WithFix : String;
var
  fTCustomIdHTTP: TCustomIdHTTP;
  fresp: TMemoryStream;
  fMySL : TStringList;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    fTCustomIdHTTP:= TCustomIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      fresp := TMemoryStream.Create;
      fMySL := TStringList.Create;
      try
        fTCustomIdHTTP.Get('https://au-api.basiq.io', fresp);
        fresp.Position := 0;
        fMySL.LoadFromStream( fresp );
        result := fMySL.Text;
      finally
        fMySL.Free;
        fresp.Free;
      end;
    finally
      fTCustomIdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      result := e.Message;
    end;
  end;

end;

{ TCustomIdHTTP }

constructor TCustomIdHTTP.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  with IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL do begin
    OnStatusInfoEx := Self.OnStatusInfoEx;
  end;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

procedure TCustomIdHTTP.OnStatusInfoEx(ASender: TObject; const AsslSocket: PSSL;
  const AWhere, Aret: TIdC_INT; const AType, AMsg: String);
begin
  SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(AsslSocket, Request.Host);
end;

end.
```

Comment: [Indy calls `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name()` internally](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/client-side-sni-support-added-to-tidssliohandlersocketopenssl/) when establishing an outbound TLS connection, and has for several years now, so if you still have to resort to calling `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name()` manually when using `TIdHTTP` then you are using an outdated version of Indy and need to update.

Comment: we are using XE5 - i managed to get indy updated but the REST Components use delphi IPPeerAPI.pas code - getting access violations when calling the TRESTClient.Create('URL')